# Uncaught Error: application '<appname>' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: undefined

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa-angular

I am using Single-SPA-angular  in micro-front-end and Single-SPA version 5.3.4 in Root application.

main.single.spa.ts in micro-front-end looks like this

I am getting following error  when i am trying to run my child application via shell application
using single spa angular

```
  Uncaught Error: application 'torinit' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: undefined
    at l (app-errors.js:87:16)
    at a (app-errors.js:6:26)
    at load.js:109:13
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:409:30)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:169:47)
    at zone.js:1326:38
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:35)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:51)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:632:39)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:529:25)
```

my helper class

```
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015';
import { filter, map } from 'https://dev.jspm.io/rxjs@6/_esm2015/operators';

export class EventBusService {
   

  constructor() {this.subject$ = new Subject(); }

  emit(event) {
    this.subject$.next(event);
  }

  on(eventName, action) {
    return this.subject$.pipe(
      filter( (e) => e.name === eventName),
      map( (e) => e["data"])).subscribe(action);
  }
}

var EventBus= new EventBusService;


System.import('single-spa').then(function (singleSpa) {
  console.log(System.import('app1'));
    singleSpa.registerApplication(
      'app1',
      function () {
        return System.import('app1');
      },
      function (location) {
        return true;
       // return location.pathname.startsWith('/app1');
      },
      { EventBus: EventBus }
    );

    singleSpa.registerApplication(
      'app2',
      function () {
        return System.import('app2');
      },
      function (location) {
       return true
        // return location.pathname.startsWith('/app2');
      },
      { EventBus: EventBus }
    );
    singleSpa.registerApplication(
      'torinit',
      function () {
        return System.import('torinit');
      },
      function (location) {
       return true
        // return location.pathname.startsWith('/app2');
      },
      { EventBus: EventBus }
    )
      console.log('in helper.js');
    singleSpa.start();
  })
```

and my main.ts in root application looks like this

```
import { enableProdMode, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { ɵAnimationEngine as AnimationEngine } from '@angular/animations/browser';

import { singleSpaAngular, getSingleSpaExtraProviders } from 'single-spa-angular';


import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { singleSpaPropsSubject } from './single-spa/single-spa-props';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const lifecycles = singleSpaAngular({
  bootstrapFunction: singleSpaProps => {
    singleSpaPropsSubject.next(singleSpaProps);
    return platformBrowserDynamic(getSingleSpaExtraProviders()).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  },
  template: '<app-root />',
  Router,
  NavigationStart,
  NgZone,
  AnimationEngine,
});

export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I was having the same issue. On debugging came to know that, when the single-spa is searching for the route to bootstrap, it's coming undefined. in my case in my index.ejs I was giving a wrong endpoint like "app-name":""//localhost:8080/main.js", but when tried with "app-name":"//localhost:4201/main.js", the issue got fixed. again you can check app-routing.module.ts , providers: [{provide:APP_BASE_HREF, useValue:'/'}], is given in @ngModule or not.